# SuiteScript API role will not show up on integration partner

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

and thanks, I am setting up a restlet integration, I have done this in the past, for some reason the API role for the integration will not show up on the partner record I have created so I can assign it. I checked my work against the docs and I have followed them faithfully. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure *Partner Role* is enabled in **Roles** to assign a role to Partner Record.[image: Check selected text for reference]

Comment: There are other roles in the list just not the one I need, or am I not understanding you? It looks like you are saying that there is a "Partner Role" setting that needs to be enabled. The second part of that is where I am getting lost. It has to be enabled in "Roles"? Where exactly? What list of "Roles"? thanks for this.

Comment: First you need to update ROLES and not Partner record.You can find role under **Setup  > Users/Roles > Manage Roles** and edit the role that you want to assign to partner record.

Comment: Once you update Roles to be assigned to Partner records, you can then go to partner record and select the role.

Comment: I truly appreciate this. I knew about Manage Roles, and I looked there. When I look at the role I need I do not see any place to "Enable Partner Role" and any similar wording. Thanks

Comment: check out the image and the selected field in it. FYI, its internal id is _partner_

Comment: OK, that choice is not even on my instance. I thought I was missing it, mine ends with "Support Role", all right thanks very much, I appreciate your effort, they have either restricted something or don't have the proper modules installed. Anyway thanks again